# Longitude deadband of geostasionary satellite

Tags: geostationary, coordinates

[image]

I try to count longitude deadband of geostationary satellite (0.1 degree). But I still confused, where should the longitude I have to start? In the picture, should I start the longitude from the far left side (about 108.26 degree) then continue to the right, or from the maximum longitude (108.29 degree) and continue to the right.
Thank you so much

Comment: Hmm... I'm no expert, but I think a satellite's longitudinal deadband is the range in longitudes that it needs to remain within. There's nothing in this image that tells us where it *should be* nor is there any evidence that there is any control or station keeping happening. So I don't know if it is possible to determine an actual deadband for this apparently uncontrolled, drifting satellite. But like I say, I'm no expert.